# Can I use an ignored property across threads with Realm?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, realm

For an object shared between threads (via persisting and querying), will changes to an ignored property made in one thread be visible in another thread?

> To share objects between threads or re-use them between app launches you must persist them to a Realm ... all changes you make to it will be persisted (and must be made within a write transaction). Any changes are made available to other threads that use the same Realm when the write transaction is committed.

http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.91.1/#writes

It looks like this *doesn't* apply to ignored properties. Each thread's instance of the object has its own copy of the ignored property, and changes in one thread don't affect any other threads. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. When you access an `RLMObject` from another thread by re-querying for it, it will be a new instance of the object, so the ignored properties will not be carried along with that one.

That being said, as long as you don't try and access any of the Realm-backed properties (Else a `RLMException` will be triggered), you CAN pass an `RLMObject` instance from one thread to another and still continue to access its ignored properties on the new thread.